# Using boto to delete all buckets

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I've been tasked with creating a script to delete all the current S3 buckets and create some new ones. This is something that they want to do on an ongoing basis. So far I have all the preliminaries:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto.s3.connection
from __future__ import print_function

conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1',
                                 aws_access_key_id='my_access_key', aws_secret_access_key='my_secret_key')

ls = conn.get_all_buckets()

print(*ls,sep='\n')
```

This gives me a list of all the current buckets. Now if I want to remove the buckets my understanding is that they have to be emptied first, using a method something like:

```
db = conn.get_bucket('bucket_name')
for key in db.list():
  key.delete()
```

And then I could do:

```
conn.delete_bucket('bucket_name')
```

I want to set it up such that it pulls each bucket name from 'ls', but I'm not sure how to go about this. I tried this:

```
for i in ls:
    db = conn.get_bucket('i')
    for key in db.list():
        key.delete()
```

But I get an error "S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request". I'm getting a sneaking suspicion that it's not pulling the separate elements from the list. Do I maybe have to get data frames involved? As far as I know, boto doesn't have an option to just nuke all the folders outright.

Comment: It would be better to use the boto3 s3 client. It has a funtion - list_buckets which returns a dictionary. You could iterate over it to empty the buckets. In fact you could use the delete_objects function which accepts 1000 keys at once. http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_buckets
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects

Comment: A quick warning - if you have buckets with a "human facing" name - i.e. "mybucket" and not an auto-generated name (like a GUID) then you run the risk of losing that bucket name between when you delete them and when you re-create them.  That may not be an issue if you don't care about the names.

Comment: The awscli supports removal of a bucket, even if it contains objects: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html.

Comment: Shouldn't `conn.get_bucket('i')` be  More like `conn.get_bucket(i)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend using [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

The following should do the trick, though it's untested (I don't want to delete all my buckets :))

```
import boto3

client = session.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

buckets = client.list_buckets()

for bucket in buckets['Buckets']:
    s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket['Name'])
    s3_bucket.objects.all().delete()
    s3_bucket.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This gives me the error "'s3.Bucket' object has no attribute 'object'" on the second-last line. I wonder if the problem is on my end.

Comment: I made a typo!  Sorry about that. Should be `s3_bucket.objects.all().delete`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you. I got some credential errors, but I will check with the boto team for that one. I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Worked for me, the only change now 2020 I guess is `client = boto3.client('s3')` rather than `client = session.client('s3')`, thanks!